# Check conditions into if check

Tags: java

I use this code to calculate the padding of a button on a page from the browser border.

```
        Dimension dm = new Dimension(1024,768);
        //Setting the current window to that dimension
        driver.manage().window().setSize(dm);

        // Click Login button to submit login form
        WebDriverWait loginButtonWebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);

        WebElement loginButtonWebElement = loginButtonWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("login")));

        int loginButtonX = loginButtonWebElement.getLocation().getX();
        int loginButtonY = loginButtonWebElement.getLocation().getY();
        int loginButtonWidth = loginButtonWebElement.getRect().getWidth();
        int loginButtonHeight = loginButtonWebElement.getRect().getHeight();
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + loginButtonX + " pixels from left border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + (screenWidth - loginButtonX + loginButtonWidth) + " pixels from right border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + loginButtonY + " pixels from top border.");
        System.out.println("Login Button is " + (screenHeight - loginButtonY + loginButtonHeight) + " pixels from bottom border.");

        // We need to check that the size is not less than 10 pixels. If the space is less trow exception and fail the test.
        assertThat(loginButtonX).isGreaterThan(5);
        assertThat(loginButtonY).isGreaterThan(5);
```

I need to implement some check like this:

```
(window_width - loginButtonWidth) < loginButtonX < window_width
```

and

```
0 < `loginButtonY` < loginButtonHeight.
```

Do you know how I can implement properly check like this:

```
if((screenWidth - loginButtonWidth) < loginButtonX < screenWidth){

}
```

Now I get error: `Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'int'`. How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`(screenWidth - loginButtonWidth) < loginButtonX` returns `true` or `false` based on whether the condition is true. So in your case, the statement `(window_width - loginButtonWidth) < loginButtonX < window_width` would be equal to:

```
if(true/false < number)
```

Which gives you the error: `Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'int'`, since you cannot check whether a boolean is bigger or smaller than a number.

You should be doing the following:

```
int subtracted = screenWidth - loginButtonWidth;
if(subtracted < loginButtonX && subtracted < screenWidth){

}
```